# C Library Callback in C++ without pointer to "this"

Tags: c++, callback

I have a C library here which I want to wrap in a C++ class. The library works asynchronous and needs to set an error handler. I know how to wrap an error handler in a static class function for a C library, but I am used to having something like a `void *user_data` pointer, where I can put `this` in to call a member function from the static thunk.

Is there a way to register the callback for a member function directly, as this library does not feature a pointer to some userdata?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in your own static function which is aware of some global (or static local) object on which it is to operate. You can even make this function a static method if want, but you can't call a method on an object without supplying an object on which it is to be called.

**Edit** : having thought about it for a while, maybe there is a way.  You can essentially emulate thread-local storage by having a global collection of collections of states indexed by thread id.  Within each thread-bound collection of states you can keep a stack/queue (depending on how the data are processed) of calling objects.  The callback can look up the stored queue (because the callback knows the thread id in which it is running).  This would allow you to force a single-threaded framework to operate on multiple streams of data.

Comment: Hmmm I thought so. The problem is that this will only work if I got 1 instance of the object. This will get fuzzed up with multiple instances :(

Comment: What do you want to happen?  Conceptually, a function which doesn't take an input at runtime, must have that "input" hardcoded at compile time.  You can add some mechanism for tracking, but if you are getting callbacks which don't care who registered them, then the best you can do is have a pool of independent call back handlers.

Comment: BTW, you should make sure you are not overcomplicating the problem.  Are you sure the framework does not rely on you pre-registering some global-state data structures?  They may not be passed to the callback directly, but if there is a global state kept within the framework, you can rely on the stream processing to be done within one thread.  And then you can keep a global stack/queue of data morsels which your callback can process one at a time.